# Segmentation fault в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, segmentation-fault

Есть такая библиотека для python pyfestival которая "делает" синтез речи(https://github.com/alex-eri/pyfestival). Так вот при вводе в python3 команды `festival.textToWavFile('Привет Мир')` вылезает ошибка `Segmentation fault` и терминал выходит из python. Но если вводить английский текст то-есть `festival.textToWavFile('Hello world')` то все нормально. Прошу помогите

Comment: Дык может он просто русский не умеет? :)

Comment: @nobody Нет умеет, у меня все работало, но потом я перестановил linux так, что все он умеет

Comment: То есть ваш скрипт раньше работал, а потом вы переустановили операционную систему и стали получать ошибку? В этом случае стоит искать, что изменилось с переустановкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось банальной переустановкой festival и festvox-ru